# Item List Layout showing up in Android Studio, but not in Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

I am working on an Android App with a Recyclerview that contains a Listview. The problem is, that the Listview items are showing up in Android Studio, that there are no errors in the XML but still, the Listview items are not showing up on the Emulator or on a Real device. I checked the Layout for all kinds of problems - Size, Width, Layout Constraints -, but I couldn´t find any. As I am stuck here, I would kindly appreciate any help or hints from the community, thanks in advance.

The Activity:

```
package com.example.xxx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Credentials;

import static com.example.xxx.SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.TAGG;
import static com.example.xxx.SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.palNo;

/**
 * An activity representing a single Main detail screen. This
 * activity is only used on narrow width devices. On tablet-size devices,
 * item details are presented side-by-side with a list of items
 * in a {@link MainListActivity}.
 */
public final class ProductDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,
        PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public Context context;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private StockBookingsRecyclerviewAdapter recyclerviewAdapter;
    private RecyclerTouchListener touchListener;
    public static final String TAG = "Barcode ist:" ;
    public String bookingType = null;
    public String itemNo = null;
    public String ean = null;
    public String quantity = null;
    public String packageCode = null;
    public String target = null;
    public String source = null;
    public Date date;
    public String scannedCode = null;
    public static final String Profile_Prefs = "Pro_File";
    public static SharedPreferences profile;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);
        TextView titleBooking = findViewById(R.id.title_booking);
        TextView typeBooking = findViewById(R.id.type_booking);
        TextView nameBooking = findViewById(R.id.name_booking);
        TextView dateBooking = findViewById(R.id.date_booking);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rowFGP);
        String selectedItem =null;

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.mockdata, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        String basic = Credentials.basic("xxx", "xxx");
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
        recyclerviewAdapter = new StockBookingsRecyclerviewAdapter(this);
        Intent newIntent = getIntent();
        String receivedPalNo =  newIntent.getStringExtra("palNo");
        String receivedNo =  newIntent.getStringExtra("no");
        String receivedType =  newIntent.getStringExtra("type");
        String receivedRack =  newIntent.getStringExtra("rack");
        String receivedCountItems =  newIntent.getStringExtra("count_items");
        RestClient.getStockBookings(getApplicationContext(),recyclerviewAdapter,basic);
        Log.d(TAGG,"Intent 1" + receivedPalNo);
        Log.d(TAGG, "Intent 2" + receivedNo);
        Log.d(TAGG, "Intent 3" + receivedType);
        Log.d(TAGG,"Intent 4" + receivedRack);
        Log.d(TAGG, "Intent 5" + receivedCountItems);

        //use a GradientDrawable with only one color set, to make it a solid color
        GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
        border.setColor(0x00000000); //white background
        border.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000); //black border with full opacity

        final ArrayList<StockBookings> stockBookingList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerviewAdapter. setBookingList((ArrayList<StockBookings>) stockBookingList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerviewAdapter);

        touchListener = new RecyclerTouchListener(this,recyclerView);
        StockBookingsRecyclerviewAdapter finalRecyclerviewAdapter = recyclerviewAdapter;
        touchListener
                .setClickable(new RecyclerTouchListener.OnRowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRowClicked(int position) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIndependentViewClicked(int independentViewID, int position) {

                    }
                })
                .setSwipeOptionViews(R.id.delete_task)
                .setSwipeable(R.id.rowFGP, R.id.rowBGP, new RecyclerTouchListener.OnSwipeOptionsClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSwipeOptionClicked(int viewID, int position) {
                                stockBookingList.remove(position);
                                finalRecyclerviewAdapter.setStockBookingList(stockBookingList);
                    }
                });

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent setIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainListActivity.class);
        startActivity(setIntent);
    }


    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item: " +item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search_item:
                // do your code
                return true;
            case R.id.upload_item:
                // do your code
                return true;
            case R.id.copy_item:
                // do your code
                return true;
           /* case R.id.print_item:
                // do your code
                return true;*/
            case R.id.share_item:
                // do your code
                return true;
            /*case R.id.bookmark_item:
                // do your code
                return true;*/
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            navigateUpTo(new Intent(this, MainListActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(touchListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
}
```

The Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="@drawable/border_set"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerview2">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/product_bookings"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txt1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/nicht_uebertragen"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txt1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_280sdp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        tools:itemCount="7"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        tools:listitem="@layout/product_item" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_110sdp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerview2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fab_content_desc"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Product Item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_border"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowBGP"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/delete_task"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/img_delete"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:layout_height="59dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_red"
                    android:text="@string/edit_article"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    app:tint="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowFGP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_booking"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/product_bookings"
                android:textFontWeight="900"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.888" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type_booking"
                android:text="@string/booking_type"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.265"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.615" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_booking"
                android:text="@string/name_booking"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.265"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.615" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_booking"
                android:text="@string/date_booking"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textFontWeight="900"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.888"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: stockBookingList is empty.

Comment: @AbhishekSoni: Ok, thanks so far - but the strings in the Listview item should show up, even when there is no data. Why isn´t that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the Adapter, `stockBookingList` is empty.

This means that when RecyclerView decides to render items on the list, it finds the `itemCount` to be 0.

This instructs the RecylcerView to not render anything on the list, since it won't call `onCreateViewHolder` or `onBindViewHolder` – two methods responsible for inflating your list item and setting necessary data.

If you have a static list of items, you need to provide them to the adapter.

If the list is coming from your `RestClient`, you need update the adapter as and when you receive data from your API.